# JQuery 3.5 Differentiating Submit Syntax

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

In JQuery 3.5 I've been struggling with understanding the submit button syntax. Can someone please clarify when to use this Ex.A:

```
        $(document).on("submit", "#new_device", function(e) {...
```

And this, Ex.B:

```
        $("#device_box_form_"+i).on("submit", function(e) {...
```

(Note, the 'i' here is a variable in a for loop generating an integer.) Ex.B's syntax works for my dynamically generated forms but for some reason doesn't work for Ex. A. I just don't understand why one syntax works for a form but not for others? I'm missing something in my understanding of the syntax.

Comment: The first code example is using a delegated event handler. You would use it when the `#new_device` element is added to the DOM *after* document.ready fires. Also note that the `on()` function was added in jQuery 1.7, not 3.5. If you have a specific problem I would strongly suggest you delete this question and post a new one with specific details of what you're trying to do and why it's not working.

Comment: Also note that using incremental `id` attributes is a ***big*** code smell. Use common classes on all the dynamic elements and remove the loop.

Comment: `$(xxx)` only works for xxx elements that **exist at the time the code runs** - if your form with #new_device is generated after the code runs, it doesn't get the event, so you need the first syntax, as noted above, for a delegated event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on("submit", "#new_device", function(e) {...
```

This will binds a click event to the document and all child elements within it. Means dynamically created elements will be having the event by default.

```
$("#device_box_form_"+i).on("submit", function(e) {...
```

Binds the click event to the event directly on the element once we loaded page.